# How To Translate Checkout Card Field Labels

Tags: localisation

I've created a translate.csv in my theme folder and confirmed working.

However, it's not working for labels that contain special characters.

I'm looking to change the wording for the following labels:

```
Credit/Debit Card Type
Credit/Debit Card Number
Security Code (CVV)
```

As mentioned `Name on Card` and `Expiration Date` work fine.

I'm assuming it is the special characters causing the issue (the "/" and "()")

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to know how magento translate work.
First thing is to actually prepare words for translating. Translations will not work if we don’t use proper string for them. So string will look like this:

```
<?php echo $this->__('desired word') ?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo $this->helper('your_helper_name')->__('desired word') ?>
```

Magento will only translate anything if written this way.

**Update**

In order to translate payment blocks (magento default payment) just go to `app/locale/your_locale/Mage_Payment.csv` and do changes there. I can see they have `"Check / Money Order","Check / Money Order"` by default, that means it is definitely possible to translate.

**Update 2**

In-order to avoid editing core files, you can copy this as follow: `design/frontend/locale/your_locale/Mage_Payment.csv`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that. But the string has not been constructed by me. It is output in method.phtml which relates to `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods` as it calls the form html with `$html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)`. So this complicates things. I can't work out the block file so I don't know how to change it from there. Which is why I am trying to use translate. translate.csv works for strings without special characters, which is why I think it does not work, for some reason, for strings containing special characters.

Comment: What is your payment method for this?

Comment: Check my updated answer too.

Comment: You're a life saver Adarsh. They were in the `app/locale/your_locale/Mage_Payment.csv`. So the problem for me was that they were already being translated, so I needed to reference the original string rather than the translation in my new translate.csv. All works, thanks :)

Comment: Glad it helped. In-order to avoid edit core files, you can copy this as follow: `design/frontend/locale/your_locale/Mage_Payment.csv`.

Comment: Great, thanks. Another problem if you wouldn't mind. Translation worked great for most of the payment field tags, apart from one - `SECURITY CODE (CVV)`. I have done the same with this translation as the rest of the working ones by referencing it in the `frontend/package/theme/locale/my_locale/translate.csv` file. I have also tried putting a copy of the relevant csv in `design/frontend/locale/my_locale/Mage_Payment.csv` and changing it in there. No luck. I also noticed it was referenced in `Mage_Checkout.csv` so I did the same with that - no cigar. Any ideas?

Comment: In my fresh magento install I couldn't find 'Security Code (CVV)` but instead found `Card Verification Number`. Could you add screenshot or provide link if possible.

Comment: Here's [Mage_Payment.csv](http://i.imgur.com/adND18A.png) and [Mage_Checkout.csv](http://i.imgur.com/kTbz6BL.png) found in `app\locale\en_GB`. Here's [translate.csv](http://i.imgur.com/Ohz8hDx.png) found in `app\design\frontend\my_package\my_theme\locale\en_GB`. All translations work, **apart from the cvv** field. Thanks Adarsh